# Installing QGIS 3.4 and 2.18 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I see [from this older post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155847/installing-two-versions-of-qgis-in-ubuntu/220684) that it was not possible to install two versions of QGIS on the same Ubuntu box with out using a virtual environment.  Now that we are a bit farther along I am wondering if this is now possible.

I would like to have my current QGIS version (3.4) but I would also like to have QGIS 2.18 installed.  Can I do this using regular installation methods or do I need to create a virtual box for the second QGIS installation?

Comment: "*Now that we are a bit farther along*" It's actually going to get harder in future as QGIS 2.18 and Python 2 are both end-of-life.  You could install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and use the `conda` package manager to create a conda environment with QGIS 2.18 https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis. This

Comment: Thanks @user2856.  This looks like it install QGIS 3.1. I understand that QGIS 2.18 and Python 2 are in deprecation.  I am hoping to get 2.18 installed to take advantage of some of the plugins not available in 3.4 until those get ported to 3.4.  Like my linked post warns - will there be a conflict since both 2.18 and 3.4 have the same name in Ubuntu?  Will your conda trick mitigate those issues?

Comment: No, you can install [2.18](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis/files?version=2.18.19). Just specify `qgis=2` in your `conda create` command, i.e `conda create -n qgis2 -c conda-forge qgis=2` then `conda activate qgis2` to activate the environment and `qgis` to run it. There won't be conflicts, the conda environment is installed separate to and isolated from the system QGIS.